# How to get view for join query with linq

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Firstly, I am so new on .Net MVC and sorry if there is any missunderstanding.

I have been searching this issue since 2 days but unfortunately, I could not find an answer.

I am trying to make join query on linq and want to take to View by listing.

Thank you in advance,

My Controller;

```
                var QueryTransferList = (from t in db.Transfers
                                    .OrderBy(item => item.Date)
                                    .ThenBy(item => item.TransferTime)
                                    .ThenBy(item => item.GuestName)
                                    join s in db.StatusDurums
                                    on t.Status equals s.StatusName
                                    where
                                        t.Date >= todaysDate &&
                                        t.Date <= todaysDate
                                    select new { t, s }).ToList();
            return View(QueryTransferList);
```

My View;

```
@model IEnumerable<NuvoTTMS.Models.Transfer>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-center">@Html.ActionLink(item.Id.ToString(), "Edit", new { id = item.Id })</td>
                        <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Reference)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GuestName)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.From1)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.To1)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Assistance)</td>
                        <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pax)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FlightNumber)</td>
                        <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TransferTime)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TransferVehicle)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TransferSupplier)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DriverName)</td>
                    </tr>
                }
```

Error Code;

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType6`2[NuvoTTMS.Models.Transfer,NuvoTTMS.Models.StatusDurum]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[NuvoTTMS.Models.Transfer]'.
```

What I did;

1. I also specified column names like

> select new { t.Assistance, s.StatusId }).ToList();

2. And also I use "AsEnumerable()" instead of .Tolist();

### **###Updated###**

I really thank you for your quick response. I just follow your comments and It is working well.

As you may see my below codes that I want to send all columns to view. Do I need to write all column names one by one as below or is there any other way to do it?

```
var QueryTransferList = (from t in db.Transfers
                                    .OrderBy(item => item.Date)
                                    .ThenBy(item => item.TransferTime)
                                    .ThenBy(item => item.GuestName)
                                     join s in db.StatusDurums
                                     on t.Status equals s.StatusName
                                     where
                                         t.Date >= todaysDate &&
                                         t.Date <= todaysDate
                                     select new NuvoTTMS.Models.TransferViewModel
                                     {
                                          Id = t.Id,
                                          Date = t.Date,
                                          Service = t.Service,
                                          Nationality = t.Nationality,
                                          Reference = t.Reference,
                                          GuestName = t.GuestName,
                                          From1 = t.From1,
                                          To1 = t.To1,
                                          Assistance = t.Assistance,
                                          Pax = t.Pax,
                                          FlightNumber = t.FlightNumber,
                                          TransferTime = t.TransferTime,
                                          TransferVehicle = t.TransferVehicle,
                                          TransferSupplier = t.TransferSupplier,
                                          Notes = t.Notes,
                                          InvoiceCode = t.InvoiceCode,
                                          InvoiceRate = t.InvoiceRate,
                                          Status = t.Status,
                                          DriverName = t.DriverName,
                                          StatusId = s.StatusId,
                                          StatusName = s.StatusName,
                                          StatusColor = s.StatusColor

                                     }).ToList();
```

And also my last question, I combined Transfer and StatusDurum models to TransferViewModel as below. Is there any way to implement transfer and statusdurum models to TransferViewModel.

Actually, If I do any changes at transfer model then I need to do in tranferviewmodel right?

```
public class TransferViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Transfer Type")]
    public string Service { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "National")]
    public string Nationality { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Gta Reference")]
    public string Reference { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Guest Name")]
    public string GuestName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "From")]
    public string From1 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "To")]
    public string To1 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Ass.")]
    public string Assistance { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Pax")]
    public string Pax { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Flight No")]
    public string FlightNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Time")]
    public string TransferTime { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Vehicle")]
    public string TransferVehicle { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Supplier")]
    public string TransferSupplier { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Transfer Notes")]
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Invoice Rate")]
    public string InvoiceRate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Invoice Code")]
    public string InvoiceCode { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Driver Name")]
    public string DriverName { get; set; }

    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public string StatusName { get; set; }       
    public string StatusColor { get; set; }
```

Comment: You need viewmodel instead of dynamic type, or you can mark as dynamic in view input type

Answer (score 1):

Your model is of type  `IEnumerable<NuvoTTMS.Models.Transfer>` as you specified in the View:

```
@model IEnumerable<NuvoTTMS.Models.Transfer>
```

So your view should be passed the object of that type. Right now you are returning a collection of anonymous type which can't work.

You can create `IEnumerable<NuvoTTMS.Models.Transfer>` in your linq query the following way:

```
select new NuvoTTMS.Models.Transfer
{ 
  Assistance = t.Assistance,
  StatusId =  s.StatusId 
}).ToList()
```

As you have data from multiple models you want to display if that's the case you will have to create a ViewModel with those properties that are needed on the View:

```
public class TransfersViewModel
{
   public int StatusId { get; set; }
   ............
   ............
}
```

and then in View set your model to be of that type :

```
@model IEnumerable<NuvoTTMS.Models.TransfersViewModel>
```

and populate that and return it back to View in the controller action:

```
select new NuvoTTMS.Models.TransfersViewModel
{ 
  Assistance = t.Assistance,
  StatusId =  s.StatusId 
}).ToList()
```

Comment: Hi @Ehsan, thank you very much for your quick response. It is much appreciated. May I ask your attention for my updated question. Thank you in advance.